# Sql Server Management - Option to avoid scripting the collation?

Tags: sql-server, scripting, collation

I have databases with different collations.  I want to be able to script out tables from one database and create them in another.  However, when I script out the tables, it includes the collation in the column definitions.

Is there a way to exclude the collations from the generated table creation scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options

Under Scripting (in the Table/View section)

Set Include Collation to False!

Comment: Hmm.  I don't see those options in Tools -> Options.

Comment: You have to have the most current version of SSMS from what I can tell, older builds of the tool don't seem to have the options.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty lame - but do a search and replace on the script after it has been generated??

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SSMS are you using?  The full edition, or Express edition?

You'll need to apply at least SP2 for 2005 to get the scripting settongs under Tools->Options.

This doesn't need to be applied to the database servers, it can be applied to just the client tools on your admin workstation if required.